# как передать значение элемента коллекции из одного класса в другой?

Tags: c#, wpf, ссылки, коллекции

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public List<string> memberData = new List<string>();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        memberData.Add(textBox1.Text);
        memberData.Add(textBox2.Text);
        memberData.Add(textBox3.Text);
        memberData.Add((combo1.SelectedItem ?? "").ToString());
        Window2 form = new Window2();
        form.Show();
        firstWindow.Close(); 
    }
}
```

......

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    void choosing(string some)
    {
        switch (some)
        {
            case ("abc"):
                { break; }
            case ("bcd"):
                { break; }
        }
    }

    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //firstCombo.Items.Add(str);
        choosing(<элемент коллекции memberData>);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window3 form = new Window3();
        form.Show();
        secondWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

Подскажите как передать 3-й элемент коллекции `memberData` из класса первого окна в класс второго окна как аргумент функции `choosing`?

Comment: public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        choosing(memberData[2]);
    }
нужно, чтобы фактически работало так, но второй класс не видит элемент первого, как сделать так, чтобы элемент memberData[2] был виден в классе Window2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделайте метод публичным

```
public void choosing(string some)
```

и тогда сможете сделать так

```
form.choosing(memberData[2])
```